# typescript declaration: module detection and namespace

Tags: typescript, h3

I am trying to write a declaration file for h3. Please see the function [reference](https://github.com/uber/h3-js#h3).

First, I am not sure how typescript detects the definition files.

It detects my definition, if placed on a folder `/src/@types/<any filename>.d.ts`, with the below content

```
declare module 'h3-js' {
    export type h3ToGeoBoundary = any;
    ...
}
```

But, I also read you can create a folder like `/src/@types/h3-js/index.d.ts`, but it won't detect  definition if write like

```
export = h3;
export as namespace h3;

declare namespace h3 {
  export type h3ToGeoBoundary = () => void; // TODO: correct types
}
```

It doesn't matter which one works, but I am not sure how to export a namespace with first approach. With that, I get error `Property 'h3ToGeoBoundary' does not exist on type 'typeof import("h3-js")'.`

Please help with a minimal file, with a working export for `h3ToGeoBoundary`, so I can expand further.

Comment: Did you write this libdef, and if so, is it something we can include directly in the h3-js library? I’m really interested in adding TS and Flow libdefs in the published module.

Comment: @nrabinowitz I only used couple of methods from `h3-js` and do most of the work at server side. so, it is not significant to publish. I would let you know if I get time to dig deep into the whole library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since module just exports a bunch of functions you can define them as individual exports (using your first approach):

```
declare module "h3-js" {
  export function h3ToGeoBoundary(): void;
}
```

Comment: that won't work. `Property 'h3ToGeoBoundary' does not exist on type 'typeof import("h3-js")'.`

Comment: Are you importing the module like this? `import * as h3js from "hr-js";`